# Routing two subnets without hiding hosts?

Tags: networking, server, routing

I have two subnets, let's say 192.168.1.0/24 and 192.168.2.0/24, which are connected by one Ubuntu server with two interface cards (eth0 and wlan0). There are lot of descriptions using NAT in a way that the hosts are hidden behind the router. I would like to ping hosts in both subnets vice-versa. How do I need to configure the Ubuntu server?

Answer (score 0):

**The section about where and which routes to set is still a work in progress. It depends on the network topology.**

First, you have to make sure the clients on each side of the router actually use the router to send packages to the other network. That is, you'll have to set appropriate routes.

Depending on the rest of your network, there are potentially different ways to setup routing.

Let's assume the server has IP adresses 192.168.1.1 and 192.168.2.1 for `eth0` and `wlan0`.

1. There are only the two local networks. There is *no* additional router that connects either network to the internet/a third network. The server you are setting up, is the only device to perform routing.
   Simply set the IP of the appropriate interface of the server as the *default gateway* on the clients. The effect is, that any package not destined for the local network will be forwarded to the server, who in turn will forward it to the other network.
2. You have a router that connects one of the networks to the internet. Usually a router provided by your ISP. Let's pretend that's network1 and call the router netgw-1. In that case, the clients will have set netgw-1 as their default-gw. *If* netgw-1 is capable, the best way to go would be to add an entry to its routing table in the gist of

   ```
   192.168.2.0/24 via 192.168.1.1
   ```

   How to do this exactly depends on the device.

   That way the clients won't need additional routes, but the packages destined for network2 are send via netgw-1 to server to network2.

   Unfortunately this will most likely not be possible, since the router will not allow manipulating its routing table. This leaves you with the option to add an entry to the routing table on *each client*.

   **Note:** How to make routes persistent depends on the clients method of network configuration (e.g NetworkManager or `/etc/interfaces`).

   But for the purpose of testing, take a client on each network and set a route (**on the client!**).

   The current routes can be listed via `ip route show`.

   ```
   sudo ip route add 192.168.2.0/24 via 192.168.1.1 dev eth0
   ```

   This sets a route to the network 192.168.2.0/24 *using the router* 192.168.1.1, sending out packages via the interface `eth0`. You will have to adapt the command, depending on which network the client is on, and the name of the  network interface.

After that, it should be as simple as enabling IPv4 forwarding _on the server. When the option `net.ipv4.ip_forward` is enabled, the kernel will forward IP packages across the server's network interfaces.

To check the status of forwarding: `sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward`
If it is 0, enable it via

```
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

Now try to ping a across the router. If it works as desired and you'd like to make the setting persistent on reboot, open `/etc/sysctl.conf` and set

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

**Note** that you might want to setup package filters via `iptables` to forbid certain traffic, depending on your security needs. But that is a different topic.

Setting up the machine as a NAT router requires setting up `iptables` to masquerade traffic, but as your question suggests you've already read howtos about that topic.

Comment: imho, if server is not the default gateway, adding a rule to the the default gateway's routing table of each subnet is also viable solution.

Comment: @adonis You are right... This seems like the more appropriate way to go. It introduces another hop, but saves adding routes on each client. Though it won't work, if for example both networks have different gateways. But I'll expand the answer in a second. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: I think it should work. ie. net1machine->net1gw->server->net2machine->net2gw->server->net1machine

Comment: @adonis But only if the gateways allow manipulation of their routing tables. For example the router I got from my ISP won't allow me to do that :-) If the gateways supported this, a separat routing server would be superfluous anyway. Or am I missing something...?

Comment: I think you are totally right, except, maybe, from the 'superfluous'. having a different gateway for each subnet doesn't mean that those gateways are connected together (note that one of the interfaces is a wlan).

Comment: @adonis Right, not really 'superfluous'... I had a setup in mind, where one would simply bridge the gateways. That might not be possible or wanted e.g for security reasons.

Comment: @Sisyphos I expanded the answer concerning routing for the clients. Let me know if the answer is helpful to you, and please do ask back.

Comment: Thank you for that detailed explanation with background-information. I tried to keep the question as abstract as possible, but it seems now in my case it's more complicate. Point 2 describes exactly my situation: I have got a router from my ISP I'm not able to configure, so I have two gateways.

Comment: Hm... adding a route for 192.168.1.0/24 on 192.168.2.0/24 clients doesn't work. I cannot ping computers in the 192.168.1.0/24 network. Well on the ubuntu server I'm using dnsmasq for DHCP and an filtering some Internet domains for the 192.168.1.0/24 network. Maybe I need to configure a bit more on the server: e.g. the dnsmasq or forwarding by IP-Tables or add some routing?

Comment: @Sisyphos You also have to set routes in the other direction: 192.168.2.0/24 -> 192.168.1.0/24 on the clients in network2, otherwise the ICMP (ping) packages won't find their way back! Also make sure forwarding is enabled on the server. `traceroute` is your friend too :-)

Comment: @nephente I was putting routes on the clients of each subnet and it works! It's not possible to set routes on my router. So I suppose I need iptable masquerading  to let the clients access the internet?

Comment: @Sisyphos Great! Yes, if the internet router is in subnet 192.168.1.0, you need to setup your server as a NAT router for that network. In fact, because you have apparently no other router in the net 192.168.2.0, you may set the server as default-gw for the clients in 192.268.2.0. No need for an explicit route to 192.168.1.0.